# Google Web app HTML page break not working

Tags: web-applications, google-apps-script, page-break

I've got a Google Apps Script "Web App".  I am trying to create a page break for the 2 page dashboard it produces.

I've reproduced the problem with a basic web app published [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw78c4NfspZBppMlNI__U9DZyepigg4StfrlJ0loJTxGU7KKBU/exec) and here is the entire code.

```
<body>
<div>page1</div> 
<div class="break"></div>
<div>page2</div>
</body>

<style>
.break{
display:block; 
page-break-before:always; 
}
</style>
```

Is it because the web app is displayed in a single Iframe and so no break is possible?

If so - can it be split into multiple Iframes??

or is it something simple I'm missing.

EDIT:  I've also now tried

```
div.break{
 display:block; 
 page-break-before:always; 
}
```

And

```
@media print { 
 div.break{
 display:block; 
 page-break-before:always; 
 }
}
```

and that didn't change anything.  I've tried it in Chrome & IE and both ignore the page break.

EDIT 2:

I think it must be an iframe issue because if I copy my code into a plain text file and open it in Chrome it prints on 2 pages.  So using it in Apps script must ignore the break presumably because the whole thing is inside a single iframe.  hmmmm....

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, your html is displayed by Google Apps Script in `iframe`. When you try printing web app page, this `iframe` cannot be printed in several pages.

Solution: select some text inside your web app, for example *page1*, to get in context of `iframe`, then hit *Print...*, it will print just that `iframe` you selected text in:

[image]

**Edit:**

You can add 'Print...' button right to your web app page to make it more user-friendly:

```
<div>page1</div> 
<div class="break"></div>
<div>page2</div>

<!-- added print button (with class "hide-on-print" to not display it when printed) -->
<button id="print" class="hide-on-print">Print...</button>

<script>
// open print dialog on button click
document.getElementById('print').addEventListener('click', function(){
  window.print();
});
</script>

<style>
@media print {
    .hide-on-print {
        display: none
    }
    .break{
      display:block; 
      page-break-before:always; 
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Oh my goodness how weird is that!!  why on earth does that work.  It works on my live dashboard too.  Slightly bizarre that I'll have to tell my users to highlight the heading before they print it but if that's the only option....

Comment: @MrPea you can add Print button right in your web app page, please check answer edit.

Comment: ahhh  great minds think alike.  I did exactly the same.  I'm going to mark your answer as correct rather than mine as without your insight I would not have worked that out.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the credit must go to Kos for pointing out that if I highlight text in the iframe it then prints correctly - I would never have thought to try that

so now I've added a small function that prints just the iframe instead of the page itself.

```
function printall() {
 window.print();
 window.frames[0].print();
}
```

and I've added a button to the dashboard for that function.  I'll just make sure the users don't use the normal print menu.

Answer (score 0):

Please use @media print { div.break{} }  Try this.

Comment: thanks again.  still no joy. I've edited the question so you can see the whole code and a link to a test published app to see it not working.

Comment: I think it a limitation on Apps Script web apps and their use of Iframes. As when I put the code into a plain text file it works fine.